# Trisect a string

Tags: python, string, output

Write a function that takes a string "s" as an argument and splits s into, and returns a tuple (left, middle, right). If the length of the string is not evenly divisible by three your function should attempt to split the string as evenly as possible.

I have tried using for loops and string replace, strip functions which obviously did not work... I am at a loss. The code I have now outputs everything in 3's

```
def trisect(s): 
    print(tuple([s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]))
s = input("what is your string: ")
trisect(s)
```

Expected Result: Input: `"123456789012"`
                 Output: `('1234', '5678', '9012')`

Actual Result:   Input: `"123456789012"`
                 Output: `('123', '456', '789', '012')`

Comment: You are currently only getting strings of 3 characters because you have fixed the size of your substring.

`s[i:i+3]` will always be a length 3 substring, so if you get a string that is more or less than 9 characters, it will fail.

Comment: `range(a, b, 3)` means "split into N separate substrings of length 3"; it does _not_ mean "split into exactly 3 substrings".

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
for s in ["abcdef", "abcdefg", "abcdefgh"]:
    n, r = divmod(len(s), 3)
    trisections = s[:n], s[n:2*n+(r>1)], s[2*n+(r>1):]
    print(trisections)
```

**Output:**

```
('ab', 'cd', 'ef')
('ab', 'cd', 'efg')
('ab', 'cde', 'fgh')
```

---

EDIT: A generalized approach.

```
# The method.
def n_sect(s, n):
    m, r = divmod(len(s), n)
    idx_a = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        idx_b = idx_a + m + (i < r)
        result.append(s[idx_a:idx_b])
        idx_a = idx_b
    return result

# Try it yourself!
import string
for n in range(3, 5):
    for i in range(1, 27):
        s = string.ascii_lowercase[:i]
        print(n_sect(s, n))
    print()
```

Comment: Works nicely on 3 but I wish this generalized to any `n` (nice bonus!). Also, it'd be a bit more intuitive if it padded to fit from the front instead of from the back. +1 anyway.

Comment: Ah, just as I'd posted one. Nice job though, I like this.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I thought this was a duplicate, but existing threads don't seem to take into account the "as evenly as possible" requirement. Using `textwrap.wrap`, `zip` and most itertools solutions leave a dangling uneven chunk at the end. This solution chunks arbitrary values of `n` and pads from the front.

The approach is to take the quotient and remainder of the iterable's length and begin iterating by the desired chunk size. For each chunk, if there is a remainder, add 1 to the chunk. Increment the step by chunk size + 1 and decrement the remainder. If there is no remainder, yield chunks normally.

Here's the function and test code:

```
def chunk(iterable, chunks):
    if chunks < 1: 
        raise ValueError("invalid chunk size")

    q, r = divmod(len(iterable), chunks)
    i = 0

    while i < len(iterable):
        if r > 0: 
            r -= 1
            yield iterable[i:i+q+1]
            i += 1
        else:
            yield iterable[i:i+q]

        i += q


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = "".join(map(chr, range(97, 115)))

    for i in range(len(s) + 1):
        for j in range(1, len(s[:i]) + 1):
            print(repr(s[:i]), " chunk size", j, ":")
            print(list(chunk(s[:i], j)), "\n")
```

Output excerpts:

```
'abcde'  chunk size 1 :
['abcde']

'abcde'  chunk size 2 :
['abc', 'de']

'abcde'  chunk size 3 :
['ab', 'cd', 'e']

'abcde'  chunk size 4 :
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e']

'abcde'  chunk size 5 :
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

```
'abcdefgh'  chunk size 1 :
['abcdefgh']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 2 :
['abcd', 'efgh']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 3 :
['abc', 'def', 'gh']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 4 :
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 5 :
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'g', 'h']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 6 :
['ab', 'cd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 7 :
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

'abcdefgh'  chunk size 8 :
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

```
'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 1 :
['abcdefghijklm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 2 :
['abcdefg', 'hijklm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 3 :
['abcde', 'fghi', 'jklm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 4 :
['abcd', 'efg', 'hij', 'klm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 5 :
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk', 'lm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 6 :
['abc', 'de', 'fg', 'hi', 'jk', 'lm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 7 :
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl', 'm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 8 :
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'k', 'l', 'm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 9 :
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 10 :
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 11 :
['ab', 'cd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 12 :
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

'abcdefghijklm'  chunk size 13 :
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Now, writing your `trisect` function looks like:

```
def trisect(s):
    return list(chunk(s, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the string using `len(s)` and then length of the sections using `len(s) // 3` (`//` performs integer division).

From there, simply slice as appropriate:

```py
length = len(s) // 3
trisections = s[:length], s[length:length * 2], s[length * 2:]
```

Edit:

Use `length = round(len(s) / 3)`

Comment: `s = "abcdefgh"` -> `trisections = ('ab', 'cd', 'efgh')`

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to use regular division, then round `length` to the nearest integer.  That would fix the problem pointed out by @brentertainer

Comment: Rounding gives weird results, like `('abc', 'de', 'fgh')`, but at least it solves the difference problem. Brentertainer's answer gives consistent results.